# Parsing JSON with a dynamic list of objects whose names are numbers

Tags: c#, .net, json

this is the JSON I have

```
{
 "productNum":6,
 "01":
{"US_7":"pna886377847444","US_7_5":"pna886377847529","US_8":"pna886377847604","US_8_5":"pna886377847666","US_9":"pna886377847741","US_9_5":"pna886377847826","US_10":"pna886377847895","US_10_5":"pna886377847987","US_11":"pna886377848069","US_11_5":"pna886377848144","US_12":"pna886377848229","US_13":"pna886377848328","US_14":"pna886377848427"},

 "02":
{"US_7":"pna886377849103","US_7_5":"pna886377849202","US_8":"pna886377849295","US_8_5":"pna886377849394","US_9":"pna886377849493","US_9_5":"pna886377849592","US_10":"pna886377849660","US_10_5":"pna886377849745","US_11":"pna886377849820","US_11_5":"pna886377849905","US_12":"pna886377849981","US_13":"pna886377850086","US_14":"pna886377850185"}
}
```

A better view of the data:

[image: Better view]

What class should I describe to parse it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can't turn this into a class because `02` is not a valid property name.

You can try using `JObject` that comes with [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). It acts much like a `Dictionary`:

Here's a sample:

```
[Test]
public void Parse()
{
    const string src = @"{
    ""productNum"":6,
    ""01"":
    {""US_7"":""pna886377847444"",""US_7_5"":""pna886377847529"",""US_8"":""pna886377847604"",""US_8_5"":""pna886377847666"",""US_9"":""pna886377847741"",""US_9_5"":""p    na886377847826"",""US_10"":""pna886377847895"",""US_10_5"":""pna886377847987"",""US_11"":""pna886377848069"",""US_11_5"":""pna886377848144"",""US_12"":""pna88637784    8229"",""US_13"":""pna886377848328"",""US_14"":""pna886377848427""},

    ""02"":
    {""US_7"":""pna886377849103"",""US_7_5"":""pna886377849202"",""US_8"":""pna886377849295"",""US_8_5"":""pna886377849394"",""US_9"":""pna886377849493"",""US_9_5"":""p    na886377849592"",""US_10"":""pna886377849660"",""US_10_5"":""pna886377849745"",""US_11"":""pna886377849820"",""US_11_5"":""pna886377849905"",""US_12"":""pna88637784    9981"",""US_13"":""pna886377850086"",""US_14"":""pna886377850185""}
    }";

    // filtering out the "productNum:6"
    var dest =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(src)
        .Where(x => x.Value.GetType() == typeof (JObject));


    foreach (var item in dest)
    {
        var obj = (JObject) item.Value;

        Console.WriteLine(item.Key);

        foreach (var d in obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", d.Key, d.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use json.Net - http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Beyond that your question is too general. There are many ways you can go about doing it. The simple approach is to make a class, call it `Product` it's definition would something like;

```
 public class Product
 {
     int productNum;
     InnerData one;
     InnerData two;
 }
```

Before you serialize, rewrite the `01` and `02` to be `one` and `two`. `InnerData` should look something like;

```
 public class InnerData
 {
     string US_1;
     string US_2;
     // rest of US_x fields
 }
```

Then you can use the deserialize method - http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm

```
 Product prod1 = jsonConvert.Deserialize<Product>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution myself:

```
string jString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\_junk\funkyJSON.txt");
var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = deserializer.DeserializeObject(jString);
var mapDyn = result as Dictionary<string, object>;
var valueSize = ((Dictionary<string, object>)mapDyn["01"])["US_7"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .Net 4.5's **DataContractSerializer**, you can give a JSON element any variable name, while specifying its actual name with the "Name" attribute.

So your class could look like:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyData
{
     [DataMember(Name="01")]
     string Var1;

     ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx